# How do I create several triggers for the same Spring Framework @Scheduled method?

Tags: java, spring, cron, spring-scheduled

Currently we have a single schedule that would execute the method

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${SEND_SCHEDULE_1}")
public void scheduledTask() {...}
```

We are looking for a solution that would schedule the same task on two different times during the week, one timer for Mon-Sat and another timer for Sunday.

Is there something similar to JSR-000318 - @Schedules and @Schedule
like so?
    @Schedules(
    {
        @Schedule(hour=”11”, dayOfWeek=”Mon-Sat”),
        @Schedule(hour=”10”, dayOfWeek=”Sun”)
    })
    public void scheduledTask() { ... }

Comment: What spring version do you use? `@Schedules` exists since 4.0

Comment: Oh.Cool! We are using 4.1.7. I apologize I should have thoroughly checked the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Schedules.html. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Schedules`

```
@Schedules({@Scheduled(cron=""), @Scheduled(cron="")})
```